# cd to a search result with dir in cmd

Tags: windows, filesystems, cmd, dir, cd

I want to know how to change to the directory containing a particular file name, using a batch file.  First, I want to search for a particular file using the `dir` command.  I know there will only be one file found.  I then want to `cd` to the directory containing that file.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if you're only searching on the file name (edit: but only if the search uses a wildcard):

```
for /R %%i in ("myfile.*") do cd "%%~dpi"
```

(Replace `%%` with `%` if running from the command line rather than in a batch file.)

If the search doesn't use a wildcard, you could do this:

```
for /R %%i in (.) if exist "%%i\myfile.txt" do cd "%%i"
```

If you need to use the `dir` command because you want to, e.g., select only read-only files, this is another option:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /s /b /ar "readonly.txt"`) do cd "%%~dpi"
```

Comment: Your 1st code will not work as written because the FOR will iterate a value for each subdirectory, regardless whether "myfile.txt" exists. You need to add `IF EXIST "%%i"` to the DO clause.

Comment: @dbenham: ah, right.  When I tested it I was using a wildcard, in that case it works.